# Law-abiding React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm looking for a way to use my custom hook inside the map function as I render the components...

FYI, I'm totally aware of the hooks rule " **Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions**. " But I believe there is a way around it without breaking the rule....

Here's some more info:

We've got a custom hook called useCommaHook as below:

```
export const useCommaHook = price => {
  const priceArray = price.toString().split("")
  const beforeComma = priceArray.slice(0, 1).join("")
  const afterComma = priceArray.slice(1, 4).join("")
  return `${beforeComma},${afterComma}`
}
```

Which can be used to add comma for currencies while rendering:

```
const renderTours = data => {
    return data.map((element, idx) => {
        return (
          <span className="filtered-tour__description-price">
            *** --> We'd like to use our hook here to get comma for every price in the loop***
            {`from ${element.node.priceFrom}`
          </span>
        )
    })
}
```

As commented above we'd like to apply that filter to all the node prices in our array.

How would you go about solving such an issue ? any idea is appreciated.

Comment: Why not just have `useCommaHook` be a regular (non-hook) function?

Comment: because we'd like to reuse in other files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`useCommaHook` is **not** a hook! It doesn't call any of the  native hooks (`useState`, ...). Therefore the rules of hooks do not apply.

Comment: That is not right! according to React official documentation -> A custom Hook is a JavaScript function whose name starts with ”use” and that may call other Hooks.... 

Checkout the last part " may call other hooks .... "

Comment: Yup, and regular functions *may not call other hooks*.

Comment: But however, the better answer would be  that why you're using "use" and use a normal javascript function instead

Answer (score 1):

Building your own Hooks lets you extract component logic into reusable functions. But here your `useCommaHook` is a simple functional component its function is to

```
return `${beforeComma},${afterComma}`
```

You didn't even use native hooks inside `useCommaHook` and there is not state in your function and so State Hook is not applicable in your code.